# How to echo selected option value. Not select name

Tags: php, html, sql

```
<select name= "NEE_category">
                <?php
                $sql = mysqli_query($dbConn, "SELECT catDesc FROM NEE_category");
                while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<option value=\"NEE_category\">" . $row['catDesc'] . "</option>";
                }
                ?>
         </select>
```

I want to echo the selected option in PHP however using this:

```
$NEE_category = isset($_REQUEST['NEE_category']) ? $_REQUEST['NEE_category'] : null;

echo "\t<p>Event Category: $NEE_category</p>\n";
```

Returns: `Event Category: NEE_category`

How do i return the selected option value and not the name?

Comment: Your selected value *is* exactly that. You defined it yourself: `<option value=\"NEE_category\">`. That is what is submitted, not the text between options tags.

Comment: I see what I've done there, so how do i change that option so it equals the selected value from my dropdown?

Comment: I need to have a look, ive only ever used it with a simple list and not SQL. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the value to "NEE_category" instead of the values you're pulling from your database.

```
echo "<option value=\"". $row['catDesc'] ."\">". $row['catDesc'] ."</option>";
```

Comment: Last part doesn't need to be "fixed". Both are valid syntax (when a variable is in *double qoutes*, its value is automatically printed).

Comment: Good to know.  I've never done it that way.  Thanks

Comment: Though you might want to add the `$row['catDesc']` between the options tags as well ;)

Comment: Yep.  Edited.  Thanks